# Set Allow this document library to receive e-mail in Incoming E-Mail - CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library, csom, incoming-email

How to programmatically set **Allow this document library to receive e-mail** in **Incoming E-Mail** section for Document Libraries in C# code?
I could set other **Incoming E-Mail**  properties as follows:

```
rootFolder.Properties["vti_emailusesecurity"] = 1;
rootFolder.Properties["vti_emailsaveattachments"] = 1;
rootFolder.Properties["vti_emailattachmentfolders"] = "subject";
rootFolder.Properties["vti_emailoverwrite"] = 1;
```

Comment: As I know using PowerShell we can do something like this: $list.EmailAlias="sampleEmail";. But it's not supported in CSOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnableAssignToEmail property is not available in CSOM. So there is no way set incoming emails through CSOM but it's possible through PowerShell Scripts.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/7402411-enableassigntoemail-list-method-missing-on-list-ob

Answer (score 0):

Added a request to the SharePoint uservoice forum:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16411147-update-the-csom-and-rest-apis-to-allow-email-enabl